# Session is getting created in Firefox but not in Google chrome for deployed node.js react.js service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have deployed my Node.js backend service in Google cloud and frontend service as well. I am using passport.js to manage the session for google login but after user completes sign in, the session doesn't get stored in the browser.

However this is working fine in Firefox! As user clicks on google login, new page opens up where user enter credentials for google login and page closes and the page signs in the user as the session gets stored.

What can be the possible problem here? I have already checked the other Stackoverflow similar question but none helped.

I have deployed frontend here - https://subleaseit-390202.wl.r.appspot.com/ & backend here- https://subleaseit-help.wl.r.appspot.com but you won't be able to login as only @usc.edu & @ucr.edu domain are allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.